# why the fiddle code is not run as same on dropbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I download one code from dropbox .When i run my code it work.I run "simple.html"
Here is link 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a4mrvmft99u0kr7/Dj44R-fqNy

and check all my code on fiddle .It will not work fine as in browser..why 
?
http://jsfiddle.net/v4d2s/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#browser").treeview({
            toggle: function(e) {
            alert($(this).find('ul').closest.id);
            //alert('===='+this.attr('id'));
                console.log("%s was toggled.", $(this).find(">span").text());
            }
        });

        $("#add").click(function() {
            var branches = $("<li><span class='folder'>New Sublist</span><ul>" + 
                "<li><span class='file'>Item1</span></li>" + 
                "<li><span class='file'>Item2</span></li></ul></li>").appendTo("#browser");
            $("#browser").treeview({
                add: branches
            });
        });

        /*$("#swipe").click(function() {
            alert('--')
            var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: 'right' };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 700;
    // $('#test').show();
     $("#test").animate({left:'250px'});
    //$('#test').toggle(effect, options, duration);
        });*/

        $('#swipe').toggle(
    function(){
        $('#test').animate({
            position:'absolute',
            left:'50px',
            border:'1px solid black'


        }, 1500);

    },
    function(){
        $('#test').animate({
             position:'absolute',
            left:'-250px',

        }, 1500);     

});
    });
```

Comment: 403 (Forbidden) from dropbox on your content. Opening up a web browser console would tell you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a4mrvmft99u0kr7/Dj44R-fqNy

Comment: @Pogrindis do you have any solution ?

Comment: use another image hosting provider ... one which allows cross domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here lies your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/SimplyAzuma/v4d2s/1/

```
jQuery 1.8.3, 1.7.2, and 1.6.4 will work.
```

Use an older version of jQuery and it will work perfectly fine.

You are also not seeing images because your css references "images/image.png". To JSFiddle, there is no image folder. Change these to "image.png" and it should work.

Comment: images are not display

Comment: Why downvote? You have no images in the code you posted.

Comment: @NaveenSharma You asked why you code did not work in JSFiddle. I made it work. You have no images in your code on the JSFiddle. Just change the jQuery version and whatever you are trying to do will work. Either that, or update your JSfiddle to have images.

Comment: Sir but In my dropbox there is images and it look good when you run my drp box

Comment: Please open this link and download that folder and check what is the output of html file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v4d2s/ please check fiddle .In that external resource have images

Comment: chn you suggest the solutin

Comment: Remove the unnecessary downvote and I will continue to help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51345/discussion-between-naveen-sharma-and-mathew-maclean)

Comment: Naveen : all of your images are forbidden.because css loads images from images folder.